# Why @JSONFormat not setting date time format correctly in Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, datetime-format

I have a Spring Boot API where in JSON request Date field is send but in application code it is not getting formatted correctly and hence DB call is failing due to binding issue

This field is sent in JSON request :-

```
 "created_at": "2014-08-12 11:48:41.000000"


@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", timezone="AEST")
private Date createdAt;
```

When the `getCreatedAt()` method is called the Date is coming in format - Tue Aug 12 07:48:41 EDT 2014

But I am expecting it in same format the way it was sent

Comment: Use `private String createdAt;` instead of `private Date createdAt;` later convert it into date object.

Comment: You try by using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")` . hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Aritra, Thank for replying. I tried that also but same result.

Comment: I've the same issue. could you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Add `@JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)` annotation first and do `JsonFormat`

```
@JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", timezone="AEST")
private Date createdAt;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have added @JsonSerialize, still I do see same thing.I am getting date in format - Aug 12 07:48:41 EDT 2014                                                              Do I need to add any maven dependency to make these annotations work? Thank you

Comment: No need actually .Can you try separate class and try annotate ?

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, can you please elaborate what you are saying.

Comment: Got you,I tired what you suggested. My code looks like this, POJO class :-                            @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", timezone = "AEST")
                                                                                                            
 private Date createdAt; public Date getCreatedAt() {
  System.out.println(createdAt);
  return createdAt;
 }

 public void setCreatedAt(final Date createdAt) {
  this.createdAt=createdAt;

 }

Comment: And CustomDateSerializer is the same as the link you sent. Still no luck. please assist.

Comment: It could be fine if you share the code how you are deserialize the code?

Answer (score 0):

`@JsonFormat` annotation is used to specify the format that will be used to serialize the property and seems to be doing it right. when you call `getCreatedAt()` you will get a `Date` object and it is up to you how you want to format it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LocalDateTime like this:

@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
@JsonProperty("create_time")
LocalDateTime createTime;

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

you need this dependency